# Rails Stripe Source Payment only present if I reload my custom form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments, stripe.js

I try to implement Stripe using a custom form in a rails app. I have a "plan" page to allow the user choose the plan he wants. It redirects to the charge custom form with the plan name in get parameter.

When I submit the form I get the following error:

> This customer has no attached payment source

However, if I reload the form and submit it again, it works well...

Any idea where is the issue?

Custom form:

```
<%= form_tag charges_path, method: 'post', id: 'payment-form' do %>   <span class="payment-errors"></span>

  <label class="amount">
      <span>Amount: <%= pretty_amount(@amount) %></span>
    </label>

  <div class="form-row">
    <label>
      <span>Card Number</span>
      <input type="text" size="20" data-stripe="number"/>
    </label>   </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <label>
      <span>CVC</span>
      <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="cvc"/>
    </label>   </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <label>
      <span>Expiration (MM/YYYY)</span>
      <input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp-month"/>
    </label>
    <span> / </span>
    <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="exp-year"/>   </div>

  <input type="hidden" name="plan" value="<%= params['plan'] %>" />

  <button type="submit">Submit Payment</button> <% end %>
```

assets/javascripts/charges.coffee

```
jQuery ($) ->
  $('#payment-form').submit (event) ->
    $form = $(this)
    # Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
    $form.find('button').prop 'disabled', true
    Stripe.card.createToken $form, stripeResponseHandler
    # Prevent the form from submitting with the default action
    false
  return

stripeResponseHandler = (status, response) ->
  $form = $('#payment-form')
  if response.error
    # Show the errors on the form
    $form.find('.payment-errors').text response.error.message
    $form.find('button').prop 'disabled', false
  else
    # response contains id and card, which contains additional card details
    token = response.id
    # Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
    $form.append $('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token)
    # and submit
    $form.get(0).submit()
  return
```

Charges controller:

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_plan
  before_action :amount_to_be_charged
  before_action :set_description
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def new
  end

  def create
    if @plan == "plan1-yearly"
      StripeTool.create_membership(email: current_user.email,
                                   stripe_token: params[:stripeToken],
                                   plan: @plan,
                                   description: current_user.id)
    elsif @plan == "plan1-monthly"
      StripeTool.create_membership(email: current_user.email,
                                   stripe_token: params[:stripeToken],
                                   plan: @plan,
                                   description: current_user.id)
    end

    redirect_to charge_thanks_path

  rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    flash[:alert] = e.message
    redirect_to new_charge_path
  end

  def thanks
  end

  def plan
  end

  private

    def set_plan
      if params['plan'].present? == false
        @plan = @plan
      else
        @plan = params['plan']
      end
    end

    def set_description
      if @plan == "plan1-yearly"
        @description = "Startup Yearly Plan"
      elsif @plan == "plan1-monthly"
        @description = "Startup Monthly Plan"
      end
    end

    def amount_to_be_charged
      if @plan == "plan1-yearly"
        @amount = 22680
      elsif @plan == "plan1-monthly"
        @amount = 2350
      end
    end
end
```

In my application layout:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      Stripe.setPublishableKey('<%= ENV['STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY'] %>');
    </script>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, no JS errors... I verified logging in the js file and the file is loaded.

Comment: I still get the same error by loading the script like this.

Comment: No $(document).ready -> in my code

Comment: I just tried, and still the error :/

Comment: Without seeing the (server-side) Stripe code you're using, it's impossible to know what might be going on here.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at this here from the Stripe docs:

https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js/v2#card-createToken

I think what's missing here is the JS call that interacts with the StripeResponseHandler. I would try replacing this: 
`Stripe.card.createToken $form, stripeResponseHandler`

with this:

```
Stripe.card.createToken({
  number: $('.card-number').val(),
  cvc: $('.card-cvc').val(),
  exp_month: $('.card-expiry-month').val(),
  exp_year: $('.card-expiry-year').val()
}, stripeResponseHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I added the script at the end of my view and now it works.